# Relacionamento entre entidades Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-jpa

Preciso adicionar uma lista de amigos a um usuário, mas qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Eu posso adicionar uma lista de User na própria entidade User e chama-la de friends? já que cada amigo também é um User

[image: Lista de usuários com nome de friends]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua pergunta ela tem várias respostas, eu vou seguir um caminho aqui, quem sabe teremos sucesso...

> Eu posso adicionar uma lista de User na própria entidade User e chama-la de friends?

**Pode!** Mas, depende muito do problema que você quer resolver, veja, na orientação a objetos existe um paradigma que é muito importante, a **abstração**.

**O que eu quero dizer**: a partir de um problema, podemos abritraí-lo de diversas formas e apresentar uma solução (umas melhores que as outras), que neste caso, é em forma de código orientado a objetos.

**Então vejamos**: na solução para o seu problema, você propós que para cada usuário possui uma lista de amigos. Esses amigos também são usuários.

Agora, por outro lado, por mais que você utilize como nome o *atributo de classe/variável de classe* (**friends**), na verdade você está abstraindo o problema da seguinte maneira: **Para cada usuário do meu sistema, ele possui uma lista de usuários.**

E no modelo de entidade e relacionamento de um banco de dados relacional, isso seria um **auto relacionamento**, ou seja, a tabela **USER** se relacionaria com ela mesma.

### Continuando

> já que cada amigo também é um User

Existe um conceito em orientação a objetos que está relacionado a sua frase acima. (**É UM** ou **TEM UM**). **Herança / Composição**

Será que esse problema se encaixa mais em **TEM UM**?

A frase ficaria: ***Cada amigo tem um usuário.***

Acho que já extendi demais. Vou colocar em baixo uma possível abstração/solução para esse problema.

```
public class Friend {
private String name;
private Integer age;
private User user;

public Friend() {

}

public Friend(String name, Integer age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public Friend(String name, Integer age, User user) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Friend{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", user=" + user +
            '}';
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

```
public class User {
private final String name;
private final String password;
private List<Friend> friends;


public User(String name, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}

public void addFriend(final Friend friend) {
    if (friend == null || friend.getUser().equals(this)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (friends == null) {
        friends = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    friends.add(friend);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    User user = (User) o;
    return name.equals(user.name) && password.equals(user.password);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, password);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", friends=" + friends +
            '}';
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public List<Friend> getFriends() {
    if (friends == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(friends);
}
```

}

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    User user_1 = new User("user_1", "1234");
    User user_2 = new User("user_2", "1234");
    User user_3 = new User("user_3", "1234");
    User user_4 = new User("user_4", "1234");

    Friend friend_1 = new Friend("Friend 1", 20, user_1);
    Friend friend_2 = new Friend("Friend 2", 25, user_2);
    Friend friend_3 = new Friend("Friend 3", 30, user_3);
    Friend friend_4 = new Friend("Friend 4", 35, user_4);


    user_1.addFriend(friend_2);
    user_1.addFriend(friend_3);
    user_1.addFriend(friend_4);

    System.out.println(user_1);

    /*
     *  user_1.addFriend(friend_1);
     *  O que acontece se eu executar esse código????
     */


}
```

}